# Function return type that matches parameter types (when using the spread operator)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Can I define a return type for the below `Mixin()` function that would resolve to an intersection type of whatever the parameter types happen to be?

```js
function Mixin(...classRefs: any[]) {
  return merge(class {}, ...classRefs);
}

function merge(derived: any, ...classRefs: any[]) {
  classRefs.forEach(classRef => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classRef.prototype).forEach(name => {
      if (name !== 'constructor') {
        Object.defineProperty(
          derived.prototype,
          name,
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(classRef.prototype, name) as PropertyDescriptor
        );
      }
    });
  });

  return derived;
}

class Foo {
  foo() {}
}

class Bar {
  bar() {}
}

class Baz {
  baz() {
    console.log('baz');
  }
}

class MyClass extends Mixin(Foo, Bar, Baz) {}

const my = new MyClass();
my.baz();
```

Without the spread operator it would be reasonably straightforward with generics. How can I ensure the type system matches what actually happens?

**Edit:** I revised the example to match the mixin function I was actually using.

**Edit:** Two follow-up questions:

1. How can I ensure all classes in `...classRefs` extend some common base class? Say I create `abstract class Mergable {}` and then only descendents can be passed to `merge`.
2. What about static properties/functions? I added a second loop to grab those, but after some experimenting I'm not sure how to have the type system aware of this:

```
function Mixin<T extends ClassType, R extends T[]>(...classRefs: [...R]):
    new (...args: any[]) => UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<[...R][number]>> {
    return merge(class { }, ...classRefs);
}

function merge(derived: ClassType, ...classRefs: ClassType[]) {
    classRefs.forEach(classRef => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classRef).forEach(name => {
          const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(classRef, name);

          if (name !== 'name' && name !== 'prototype' && name !== 'length' && descriptor) {
            Object.defineProperty(
              derived,
              name,
              descriptor
            )
          }
        });

        // Static Properties
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classRef).forEach(name => {
            // you can get rid of type casting in this way
            const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(classRef.prototype, name)
            if (name !== 'name' && name !== 'prototype' && name !== 'length' && descriptor) {
                Object.defineProperty(
                    derived.prototype,
                    name,
                    descriptor
                );
            }
        });

        // Instance Properties
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classRef.prototype).forEach(name => {
            // you can get rid of type casting in this way
            const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(classRef.prototype, name)
            if (name !== 'constructor' && descriptor) {
                Object.defineProperty(
                    derived.prototype,
                    name,
                    descriptor
                );
            }
        });
    });

    return derived;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. [The code as written](https://tsplay.dev/wQAqvw) has a runtime error; `merged.baz()` does not work in JavaScript.  Presumably by "work as expected" you mean something else...could you make this a [mcve] so it actually works at runtime?  If the question were just "can you type a function whose outputs are the intersection of the inputs", the answer is [yes](https://tsplay.dev/ND5Vlm).  But I don't think that's what `extend()` is supposed to do (since an intersection of construct signatures doesn't construct an intersection of instances) nor what it does in practice.  Help!

Comment: In my efforts to create a minimal example it seems I broke something. Will update with a working version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if it works for you:

```js
// credits goes to @jcalz
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
        k: infer I
    ) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type Infer<T> =
    T extends infer R
    ? R extends new (...args: any) => any
    ? InstanceType<R>
    : never
    : never;

type ClassType = new (...args: any[]) => any;
function Mixin<T extends ClassType, R extends T[]>(...classRefs: [...R]):
    new (...args: any[]) => UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<[...R][number]>> {
    return merge(class { }, ...classRefs);
}

function merge(derived: ClassType, ...classRefs: ClassType[]) {
    classRefs.forEach(classRef => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classRef.prototype).forEach(name => {
            // you can get rid of type casting in this way
            const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(classRef.prototype, name)
            if (name !== 'constructor' && descriptor) {
                Object.defineProperty(
                    derived.prototype,
                    name,
                    descriptor
                );
            }
        });
    });

    return derived;
}

class Foo {
    foo() { }
}

class Bar {
    bar() { }
}

class Baz {
    baz() {
        console.log('baz');
    }
}

class MyClass extends Mixin(Foo, Bar, Baz) { }

const my = new MyClass();
my.foo() // ok
my.bar() // ok
my.baz(); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGMCcFMBMEsAuBnUBzA9tViOgAIBW4AhgDYBeAsAFCICeADtKAKoB28G7AKhgJLtE0SMmjhEXdgB5WAPlABeWqFWgAFK1DQAHsPaxUJdvVAB%20DQGsAXGwCUShQDcM8WKFvtoTkQ937DDRU1EJtQeHYAMxFQfmDVB0VnV1h481i0z28RAG5aWgZmWKiRaR4FZRoQnm09aANUCOjIUAAlNItW2oDULwB3DQA6YZJINGRbY3pEhSmO4uREY3BoHiZoaVa5TNAvH0gdvdz8unXQAGEyEmRkNaLFXegB9WHB0fHJkwBtAF0Z0CmeRokQAruwJFJQABZeA6CJlbr1QKXa63dYAGjaiIaoB4vzkL2G4CuN1a0EiE1AX1erT%201jS-SGIzGlKmv3%20HCkfEEwlE4kk3GkgkWy1W62k1OGtK%207BBAFsAEYiH5yBQAbzSMEQIMg7FAcpEaGg6mJqNAatAAF9Ma9TaTycg7EDLSdQeCBXqDWNjbARPAfLBbCibndoDaiSTkGSKUHI6H2ea0naow7BpEMJAAKIkcAACxNkejjkTVRCagA8grCPzBkbEOW%20uwAAqQDDMSAMAByJANyALqOjg0YrdwhWgdjTGezefU7B7LCSJbLy9AIFA9AwIIgxnQ0EQoEgblAGEioDH28WETQ4T1iFz8FQfRI9DSK4g3EWoF9yCg8EYuBaB5K2rCRaz3Btm1bdsGAAEWwX9-wzft7UiIcRwwMdMTnA07FfFd4FPWd51AABCRQHgAcnAD9EEgEEJAzCjQAAMmYr94MPRDIAcDVSzfZdgJrX1IgiaAWzbEQGHUPD%20LLX1DwDNCMIwjEZNktRsLDNT1PYn9OIA7SVydQzVBdPiy0tYzzMsoFNT3HU9Xk-04GdE5k1AAAxDA8F4kJ0wwdQeKtWgzNodyACFRiXNQFVGQLzWCmhQpoCKSAoaLVFiih4t8ldqPYZAMDIaBBjIDA0HUCisooqyQjM5L3Khehg1QfwkVQGE4XYdQvIwTFIsgfq0qChqaP1UwHkZJqWsCoE5XoScAocNcMEsWh5sGWLIHila1poDastm1cwFWoA)

**Infer type**

```js
type Infer<T> = /*1*/ T extends infer R ? /*2*/ R extends new (...args: any) => any ? /*3*/ InstanceType<R> : never : never;
```

1. Just infers the type. [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)
2. Checks if R extends ClassType
3. If R has is a ClassType, return [`InstanceType<R>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype)

**Mixin**

```js
function Mixin</*1*/T extends ClassType, /*2*/R extends T[]>(...classRefs: /*3*/[...R]): new (...args: any[]) =>/*4*/ UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<[...R][number]>> {
    return merge(class { }, ...classRefs);
}
```

1. I have defined `T` generic as a base type for all arguments.
2. `R` serves for argument type. As You see it is an array of `T`, in other words array of classes
3. It is important to use `[...R]` instead of `T[]`. Because `T[]`, will expect that all arguments have exactly same type, which is not useful in our case.
4. `[...R][number]>` means just union of all elements in the array. Example `[1,2,3][number] === 1|2|3`. `InstanceType<[...R][number]>` means InstanceType|InstanceType|InstanceType. And `UnionToIntersection` just merges all unions into one type.

**UPDATE 3**

> How can I ensure all classes in ...classRefs extend some common base class? Say I create abstract class Mergable {} and then only descendents can be passed to merge.

Just replace `Mixin` with next one:

```js
function Mixin<T extends ClassType, R extends T[]>(...classRefs: [T, ...R]):
    new (...args: any[]) => UnionToIntersection<InstanceType<[...R][number]>> {
    return merge(class { }, ...classRefs);
}
```

Here I have explicitly defined first element with `T` generic type. Now, TS knows that `R` should extend array of `T`.

Try to use `Bar` class now without extending from `Foo`. You will receive an error

Comment: I think I'm following what is happening here, but I noticed the `Infer<T>` type isn't used anywhere, is that expected?

Comment: Oh, sorry, Infer is redundant here

Comment: @Wilco regarding static methods. Do you want to make sure that all classes have same static methods?

Comment: No the static methods can be different on each class passed to `merge()`, the idea is it would also copy them into the resulting merged class as well.

Comment: Honestly, I never had such case. I dont know how to copt static methods.

Comment: @Wilco can I use your question in my TS blog?

Comment: A bit late to reply, but sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a type function which takes a tuple and produces an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of all its elements.  The obvious way to do this is with [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types):

```
// obvious version:
type IntersectAll<T extends readonly any[]> = 
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? F & IntersectAll<R> : unknown;
```

That works, but hits recursion limits if your tuples are longer than ~20 elements.  There's a [less obvious version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) that uses contravariance in [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types):

```
// less obvious version:
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends
  ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
type IntersectAll<T extends readonly any[]> = Extract<
  UnionToIntersection<
    { [K in keyof T]: [T[K]] }[number]
  >, readonly any[]>[number]
```

Both versions should work in what follows:

---

You want `merge()` to take at least one class constructor of zero arguments (right?  I don't want to worry about what happens if your constructors need arguments to construct them), and produce a new class constructor that produces the intersection of all the instance types of the original constructors.

If so, this is the typing I would give:

```
function merge<T, U extends any[]>(
  derived: new () => T,
  ...classRefs: { [I in keyof U]: new () => U[I] }
) {
  classRefs.forEach(classRef => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(classRef.prototype).forEach(name => {
      if (name !== 'constructor') {
        Object.defineProperty(
          derived.prototype,
          name,
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
            classRef.prototype, name) as PropertyDescriptor
        );
      }
    });
  });

  return derived as new () => (T & IntersectAll<U>);
}
```

Essentially, this function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the instance type of the first constructor; and `U`, the tuple of instance types from the rest of the constructors.  So `derived` has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) `new () => T`, while `classRefs` has a tuple of construct signatures, represented by the [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where you take the elements of `U` and wrap it with `new () => ...`.  The return type is `new() => (T & IntersectAll<U>)`, a constructor that produces intersections of all the other constructors.

And `Mixin()` is similarly generic:

```
function Mixin<T extends any[]>(
  ...classRefs: { [I in keyof T]: new () => T[I] }
) {
  return merge<unknown, T>(class { }, ...classRefs);
}
/* function Mixin<T extends any[]>(
  ...classRefs: { [I in keyof T]: new () => T[I]; }
): new () => IntersectAll<T> */
```

---

```
You can verify that it works as expected:

class Foo { foo() { return 6; } }
class Bar { bar() { return "abc" } }
class Baz { baz() { console.log('baz'); } }
class MyClass extends Mixin(Foo, Bar, Baz) { }

const my = new MyClass();
console.log(my.foo().toFixed(2)); // "6.00"
console.log(my.bar().toUpperCase()); // "ABC"
my.baz(); // "baz"
```

---

There you go.  I assume there are edge cases here, since playing around with prototypes manually can do funny things.  And the intersection isn't exactly right if you mix together classes with conflicting types for the same property or method names.  And with class constructor arguments, of course.  Such edge cases might be addressable, with additional complexity... but I'd consider any of that to be out of scope here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBsFMGdtB7ARgNwJbwK52ZATtdAOwC4BYAKABcBPAB0lAFVCiAVeASUMr2kgGNKRADyMAfKAC8FUKAAUjUJAAePQgBM4AQ0LVQAfnkBrYkwCUUicnip1oU4Ug5cFlWs0z5ck6FSEAZnigHBaSVjbqFoYc9qCOzhQ09MHcvAKUAILg4MKsSqqQGnC4kFrq8ITgejrUANoAuhKSoACiqrhagsKezGycqfjpIp6yAN6gtQDSvoSgRpDU8P6grPWmtaxT9fWgAL61hBgAtoh49Z5iADSgJWUVVaA1DWIHx6e45+QU-hiEgkSgI54ADmkFy10UbkKmkeumeck86jwqBw6gckAA7vJQhJWJdPAA6In8cBaWAAJUg-mgpnGtRifjmCyWTDWcUx2MsTHpO12FAso08JLJ0Ep1IJ-nguBanQAFnJhRSqVzBeRZLIAPKIABW6QJoMoGoxhAACrh4PRcDQAHJaIHQBWkpX+Am0c2UeBJSBmCVSmX8eWEO0MMKgVXq9WoZZyINA0AAQkkzQA5PwKtBKLgMIIpcmBSMI6AtbrBASkf4-JAzRa8DQEWrCxGkbgUZB1K73Z66JB8Q3G7JYz2C43i3qDUbTebLTQACIwfgt2ge3D1-uFxWiqkdz1d+jXQcWMmgavT6hz6AL1BLqXD9VmADct75fb2D88uzfXwbJUoGFws2bVs7CPRwsTkHF5DyAAyFIeEGQQshycRP2fb5fn+CpQAAWVQZQ-FyfJ3G0OFGlXUAiQJDcxRpMMJgZWZ5kWZZVnRMCIM2DheX5MNPB-P9ZiBXBQWEX4jEIeBjWuVgxEdEVaN2a4KKoqloBQihgAAKlAH4-iETCcLwwgCKhIpYTqUjCWJJ1N2pWk6JmJkmJWNlQM5UMOPqe89n5Vi3IkLg4L4BDslyCQNOACgKA3UAADF4HgWjJXgcDaL4-9QAANi83ZvPIaKACEtFwWjECKlLxjS2YACItEQfgqr2XKCq0AAvErWvK0A00IaB4CgAlwHgYE5GTUqWrzbKmus7DqAAYWmkyYQMvw5Di+BrkK3ANtagVcqi9NKEBPRmlcrC5us8DHzy9M+sgAahrkI5qF9ZKfQ9GLcLbOQACYzAfUAQFAKqMoJAAGUGqv2nrbvu4anoJUqVze+BGFoS1ZrJSBwP+wGqoyfLZsh8h4bGy6AbAKqxqJiggA)